# "Fun" real world problem which involves solving multiple iterative simultaneous equations

Tags: linear-algebra

i'm trying to solve something that's work related and I've attempted to boil it down to a set of simultaneous equations but am unsure if its actually solvable.

I've attempted to use solver in excel but it doesn't give me an appropriate solution.

W/O further ado here's the problem...Company X will have to pay out 300 for bills incurred in a certain quarter. Some of the bills will be paid in the quarter they are incurred and some will be paid in the following quarters. For example 30% will be paid during the quarter the bills are incurred, 40% in the next quarter and 30% in the quarter after that. I am attempting to convert these quarterly statistics into monthly statistics. So we assume that the 300 is spread out over the quarter in equal proportions i.e. 100 per month.

So we have the following information:

- M1Inc, M2Inc, M3Inc = $100....amount incurred each month
- Q1 = 30%, Q2    = 40%, Q3 = 30%....amount paid each Quarter
- Q1 + Q2 + Q3 = 100% as all the bills incurred in the first quarter have to eventually be paid
- M1, M2, M3, M4 etc....the total of all of these also has to be 100% and this is what we are trying to solve for

The total amount paid during the first quarter will be:

- Q1Inc * Q1....300 * 30% = 90

Our monthly %'s need to produce the same result. How this works is....In the first month a certain % (M1) of the bills incurred in the first month (M1Inc) will be paid. In the second month a different % (M2) of those bills incurred in the first month will be paid along with M1% of the bills incurred in the second month.

Therefore the total amount paid over the Quarter will equal to:

- M1Inc*(M1 + M2 + M3) + M2Inc*(M1 + M2) + M3Inc * M1...this needs to equal 210 i.e. the result when the quarterly %'s were used

In the second quarter we assume no more bills are incurred and the amount paid will be:

- M1Inc*(M4 + M5 + M6) + M2Inc*(M3 + M4 + M5)+M3Inc*(M2 + M3 + M4)

This continues until all of the bills incurred in the first quarter are paid.

Can anyone help?? Apologies if the above doesn't make any sense at all/isnt clear/too long!

PS i actually can solve this if we assume that each Month% in the Quarter is the same. However it gave me some negative monthly %'s which dont make sense in the real world! I.e. the gas company rarely pays you money!! Thanks again